# Disable auto change orientation

Tags: android

Below is my code.
I want to set it disable auto change screen orientation.
And enable auto change screen orientation.

```
class NewLoad extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progDailog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progDailog.setMessage("test");
            progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progDailog.setCancelable(false);
            progDailog.show();
            //set disable auto change
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            //do something
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            super.onPostExecute(unused);
            progDailog.dismiss();
            //set enable auto change
        }
    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What are you trying for? If you want to disable the autoscreen rotation. [Try this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: Do you want your app to not-rotate, or do you want to system-setting to change (as some sort of widget/setting-app might want to do) ?

Comment: I want disable rotate in onPreExecute. And enable it after onPreExecute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your activity to look something like this in manifest

```
  <activity
                android:name=".Hello"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"   <-- Screen will be forced to have portrait
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize" > <-- No Restart in these cases
```

ScreenSize attribute seems to be added in 4.0 so don't mentioned it if you are ruuning below 4.0.

Comment: if i do not specify **android:screenOrientation="portrait"** it is restarting in htc v one (4.0). I do not want to fix the orientation of the activity. SO is there any way to stop restarting the activity without fixing the orientation

Comment: AFAIK when you rotate device activity will recreated to support landscape mode what you can do is save heavy lifting objects somewhere and restore them on rotation rather creating again.

Comment: ok which means i have to make use of the two golden methods onSavedInstance State and onRestoreInstance state right ?

Comment: If you are only concern about rotation then rather use getLastNonConfigurationInstance() but its deprecated now.

Comment: but if i specify android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" it  is not restarting the activity in motorolla milestone(api level 8) and samsung nexus(api level 10) even though i do not specify  **android:screenOrientation="portrait"** then y it is restarting in higher versions like htc v one

Answer (score 2):

```
disable auto change screen orientation.And enable auto change screen orientation.
```

if you want to do `at run time`

try :

1. Keep a boolean flag as per you need  as in http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/handling-configuration-changes-or-not/
2. override the onconfigurationchanged  and if it;s true pass the call to super.onconfigurationchanged   if false wouldn't pass call to super

Answer (score 1):

In runtime:

When you want to block sensor:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

When you want to activate:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation)